# Why TexStudio can not show eps-figure?

Tags: graphics, xetex, texstudio, eps, output

I am using xelatex to plot eps-image in pdf-file.

But the eps-image is not showing and I want to know why

**Something I have found：**

Case 1：
xelatex + TexStudio -> eps-image can not show, pdf-image worked

Case 2：
xelatex + Texworks -> both worked

**My TexStudio-Confi**
[image]

**Log-File**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.9.23)  9 JUL 2018 21:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.

(d:/TexLive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
File: testeps.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<testeps.eps>
File: testpdf.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use testpdf.pdf>
 [1

] (./document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 599 strings out of 492998
 7295 string characters out of 6137851
 66625 words of memory out of 5000000
 4640 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,5n,19p,203b,146s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on document.pdf (1 page).
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{testeps.eps}
    \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{testpdf.pdf} % worked
\end{document}
```

Thank you all in Advance!

**Update：**

change xelatex to pdflatex can show the eps image, but I just not understand, why xelatex in texstudio not working for eps

Comment: My info is likely out of date, but my recollection is that EPS images can only be used with `latex` and not even `pdflatex`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes me too， but using Texworks + xelatex can show the eps-image.. ..