# eps figure not showing up using XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, eps

I am trying to compile a tex file containing an **eps** image using **XeLaTeX**, here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{sim}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:sim}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

On my friend's laptop(Same Windows 10, The very same TeXLive and XeLaTeX version) it works OK but on my laptop, it produces a blank figure as below:

[image: blank figure]

I am using XeLaTeX with the following build command:

```
xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Comment: I’m not sure this is your problem but do you have Ghostscript installed on you System?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I didn't. I just installed it and the problem is still here.

Comment: First your title says Xelatex (good) which will work showing a blank figure if sim.eps is blank but body of question says Xetex which wont work and wil give other errors, suggest you find an.eps file you know is good and place that as sim.eps in same directory as .tex

Comment: @KJO sim.eps is not a blank eps, It appears blank in the generated pdf file though. I've compiled this example on two other PC's, none of them make it blank, just my own PC has got this problem.

Comment: Helps to know editor (version) my default included texworks will show eps but some other editors may not, Also are there any errors appearing  from running xelatex via command line from the tex folder ? see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439958/why-texstudio-can-not-show-eps-figure

Comment: @KJO I was running xelatex through texstudio via the mentioned build command, I just checked texworks and again the pdf shows a blank figure. My external pdf reader(summatra) shows it blank too. I don't think the problem is with pdf readers because my pdf reader shows the pdf I generated from this code sample on the other systems.

Comment: Ok have just seen what you see, 1st run on command line OK (Output written on sim.pdf (1 pg) .EPS included. Messages suggest 2nd run (Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun). 2nd run corrupted with errors (xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely file sim.pdf may not be valid. TRUE), so ran a third time , NOW I do not see the .eps content.(! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.) DELETED AUX file now back to square 1 It works with the message to run again TRY rename TEX file to a different name (...2.tex) since there are other objects in the folder that start with same name

Comment: SO   --- 1) delete old Aux files --- 2) avoid conflicting names --- 3) from cmd window run **xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode testfile2.tex** --- 4) up arrow and run it again to check no errors on second run